# Code to allow user make range selection to search list in another workbook and return cell value

Tags: vba, excel

**Info**

Workbook A: Has a master worksheet with a list of items, but the values are arranged in month columns

Workbook B: I have two sheets with different list of items I want to use to search Workbook A and return the current or specific month I need.

Note: Workbook B columns is offset, so we may need to account for this.

The code I have so far:

```
Sub Button()

Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim MyWB As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim aRange As Range

'Excel titled, "MODs", contains this module
Set MyWB = ThisWorkbook

'Ignore possible messages on a excel that has links

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename '("clients saved spreadsheet,*.xlsb")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True


If MsgBox("Please select list range to search.", vbExclamation, "Search List") = vbOK Then

On Error Resume Next
Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range", Type:=8)
If aRange Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
Else
  aRange.Select
End If

End If

End Sub
```

I might might be making this harder than I should be, so I am open to suggestions. I can't seem to find the right find function to use my selected range list and target the newly open workbook with the specific master worksheet (something similar to a vlookup).

**Version 2: with a set range but I'm still getting not value returns**

```
Sub Button()
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim MyWB As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim MyWs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim aRange As Range


'This line of code turns off the screen updates which make the macro run much faster.
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Excel titled, "MODs", contains this module
Set MyWB = ThisWorkbook
Set MyWs = MyWB.Sheets("Sheet")

'Ignore possible messages on a excel that has links
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename '("clients saved spreadsheet,*.xlsb")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Application.InputBox("Select a cell on the key sheet.", Type:=8).Parent
On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "cancelled"
Else
    MsgBox "You selected sheet " & ws.Name
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

With MyWs
    For Each aCell In .Range("A1:A10" & LastRow)
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A19" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(aCell.Row, 15) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                    aCell.Value, ws.Range("A1:C18"), 2, 0)
        End If
    Next aCell
End With

'wb.Close (False)

'If MsgBox("Please select list range to search.", vbExclamation, "Search List") = vbOK Then
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range", Type:=8)
    'If aRange Is Nothing Then
      'MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
    'Else
      'aRange.Select
    'End If
'End If

'Return to default setting of screen updating.
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think the problem I'm running into is this code:

```
With MyWs
    For Each aCell In .Range("A1:A10" & LastRow)
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A19" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(aCell.Row, 15) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                    aCell.Value, ws.Range("A1:C18"), 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

begin declaring`aCell as Range` and `lastRow as long`

You seem to miss the definition of `lastRow`, which could be something like

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

then look carefully at  `.Range("A1:A10" & LastRow)`. Assume `lastRow` were 100 then this would set a range from A1 to A10100: is that what you want? Or may be you'd use

`.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`

again `.Range("A19" & aCell.Row)` would lead to a single cell address such as "A1989" (were aCell.Row = 89): is that what you want?

other than what above I can't grasp the actual scenario of what you're searching where. You may want to provide more info about that